# Best practice for calculate user rate and more

Tags: sql, rating

I am building an application that shares some stuff...

Each Object can be rated has a rating 1..5 start. I keep for each the number of rates per star so can calculate the Avg rate.

So per Obj I have: Avg rate and total rate.
I need to get the top10 rated Obj - so can do it using AvgRate+TotalRate (those who has these values as top10).

I want to have in the server an sql table like this:
ObjId (index), totalRate, AvgRate...
If possible to have this table sorted so that can get the top10 as the first 10?
How can query the top10 with the calculation I want?

Also - I need to get the top10 per users. So per user I have all the Obj he shared so can have all of the rates of these Obj - with all info per Obj as mentioned before.

I need to know how to calculate a user rate, and also - how to fast get the top10.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if I understand but cant you just sort by ascending and limit the results to 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Later Edit: Sorry, didn't understand your question when writing this answer, gonna leave it still for others..

---

What's your formula for TotalRate ? And what do you mean by "so can do it using AvgRate+TotalRate" Why are you summing an average to TotalRate - whatever that is?

Best practice is to always compute the sums/averages incrementally.
I would model Obj like this:

- A total number of rates received
- B total sum of points received
- C average (float: B/A )
- D - foreign key to user (author/owner of Obj)

When object receives rate X, you then recompute A = A + 1, B = B + X, C = B/A.
In the same manner pre-compute aggregate sums/average. So if Obj belongs to user, create the same fields (A, B, C) to User model/table, and when Obj receives rate X, also update A, B, C values for user D (owner of Obj). Then, when selecting top 10 users, you do not need to join with Obj table (which may get huge), you only select users - descending by B or C column, limit 10.

Comment: This is the simple way - but if Obj has 1 rate for 5(for example) then it will be in the top10, but it got only 1 rate.... Clearly it cannot be in the top10 when there are Obj with rate of 4 rated by 1000 users (just example)

Comment: Total rate is 1*numOfRatesFor1Star +...+ 5*numOfRatesFor5Star... So as mentioned in the previous comment - need to get top10 according not only to the Avg rate but also using some calculation with the number of people who rated it

Comment: Ok, now I get it, you are asking for a popularity formula based on average rates and number of rates. I think you need to look for "popularity algorythms". Most take in count the frequency of the most recent rates.. so that "old" posts get burried.

Comment: Probably this is the better way to specify what I need :) Thanks will look through the net for this